# Screen иногда убивает процесс

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, telegram-bot

На виртуальном сервере запущен телеграмм бот. Подключается через PuTTY, запускаем screen и начинаем процесс. Некоторое время бот работает, но через +- 10 часов просто сам по себе киляется и выводит сообщение:

```
root@{ip}:~/папка с репозиторием/папка проекта# python manage.py Bot_telegram
Killed
```

На сервере ещё стоит вк бот, но работает он без проблем, что черезмерно странно. Объединино всё Django

Comment: Читайте в dmesg, по какой причине он оказался Killed (скорее всего нехватка памяти)

Comment: Действительно. Там с десяток сообщений out of memory

Answer (score 0):

Процессы завершались из-за того, что на сервере не хватало оперативной памяти.
Проблему мы решили, запустив процессы как демоны

Comment: Тут можно почитать о демонах:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)